# How does MVVMCross fragment navigation work in 4.0?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Since the new upgrade I have no idea on how to navigate with fragments.

A lot of code from [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus) is commented out. If I use the code that is left, it doesn't work. I get the activity not found exception. I use the same headers as written in demo example. What are the steps I need to follow to create a succesful fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new fragments are actually pretty straight forward. All you have to do is annotating your fragment classes with the [`MvxFragmentAttribute`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/7482acaeeec62a7a833956fcf02a900501257d45/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging/Attributes/MvxFragmentAttribute.cs) and then making sure that the type passed as the first argument of the `MvxFragmentAttribute` implements [`IMvxFragmentHost`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/d27276cc4f613f3d6bdce20dc8d7828290eebd9c/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging/Presenter/IMvxFragmentHost.cs), so that it can handle the Open and Close methods used by the [`MvxFragmentsPresenter`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging/Presenter/MvxFragmentsPresenter.cs).

The new `MvxFragmentsPresenter` will handle whether or not the current top Activity is responsible for showing the requested fragment or not and, if it isn't, it'll start the proper activity in before showing the fragment.