# Add transaction transition for fragments

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When I navigate to an activity using `ShowViewModel`, it is nicely animated. But when the target is a `Fragment` it won't. Is there a way to add this as well?

I saw that in native android you would add it to the `FragmentTransaction`, but since `MvvmCross` Handles that for us, I assume there is another place to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that handles the fragment transaction is the `Show` method from the activity implementing `IMvxFragmentHost` that's responsible for handling the specific Fragment being show. In order to change the animation, you need to use the [`SetCustomAnimations`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method when displaying the fragment.

What I usually do is creating a `BaseFragmentView` class that has enter and leave animations exposed as properties. When displaying the fragments, I can simply use those properties like this:

```
var transaction = SupportFragmentManager
                   .BeginTransaction()
                   .SetCustomAnimations(fragmentView.EnterAnimation, fragmentView.ExitAnimation)
                   .Replace(targetId, fragmentView)
                   .Commit();
```

When using the `MvxChachingFragmentView`, you can simply override the [`OnBeforeFragmentChanging`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a5d1a4bd667d57c3dc6d40a3ddbf50730414e6cf/MvvmCross/Droid/FullFragging/Caching/MvxCachingFragmentActivity.cs#L382-L384) method and use the second parameter to add the custom animations you want.

You can see how to implement the `IMvxFragmentHost` interface by checking the [`MvxCachingFragmentView`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a5d1a4bd667d57c3dc6d40a3ddbf50730414e6cf/MvvmCross/Droid/FullFragging/Caching/MvxCachingFragmentActivity.cs) class and, if you don't know how to use the new Fragments from MvvmCross 4, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344178/how-does-mvvmcross-fragment-navigation-work-in-4-0/35349222#35349222)

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that I lose the possibility to navigate via the ShowViewModel in the VM to a Fragment?

Comment: Negative. Under the hood, when you call ShowViewModel it eventually gets to call the Presenter which, in the case of displaying fragments, gets to call the Show method in the registered IMvxFragmentHost. This is the way it's already being handled, you'll just change it a bit to fit your needs :)

Comment: But I can't further use the MvxCachingFragmentView? As far as I can see I can't just override the ShowMethod of it and add my transition animation